# Unset php count

Tags: php, unset

I have this running at the bottom of every site I create. Because it loops do I need to unset the value. Im trying to save memory everywhere I can

```
$tagclouds = explode(",", $tagclouds);

for($i = 0; $i < count($tagclouds); $i++){
$tagworld = str_replace('-', ' ', $tagclouds[$i]);
echo "<li><a href='$domain/?tag=$tagclouds[$i]'>$tagworld</a></li> \n";
}
```

Comment: What piece of memory in particular are you worried about? Why are you worried about it?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I ran into a problem with my server with my programs eating up all the memory. I've been trying to find and fix every memory issue

Comment: You may be going down a blind alley. PHP collects memory, and _certainly_ after the script terminates. Did you profile your scripts or are you just writing every single micro-optimisation you can think of whether it makes any difference or not?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal  Well, i've been using the same system for years. I rewrote the stats program an "boom" memory issues. So after reading the PHP manual from cover to cover lol, I decided to revisit some old codes

Comment: "boom". BTW, "code" in this context is an uncountable noun, so "codes" is incorrect here.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Thanks Tom, sorry for the uncountable noun. lol again. But thanks you for your help

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to unset any counter, because you don't need any counter. Whatever happened to foreach and proper escaping?

```
<?php
foreach ($tagclouds as $tag) {
  $tagworld = str_replace('-', ' ', $tag);
  echo '<li><a href="' . $domain . '?tag=' . urlencode($tag) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($tagworld) . '</a></li>';
}
```

If you do need for-loops, make sure to put the count() in the initialization part. Otherwise the count() is executed for every iteration, making the thing slower than necessary.

```
<?php
for($i = 0, $length = count($tagclouds); $i < $length; $i++) {

}
```

Comment: Same question applies to `$tagworld` now.

Comment: @rodneyrehm urlencode($tag) and  htmlspecialchars($tagworld) are taken care of when the information is save

Comment: Sounds like a design decision I'd have agreed with, 10 years ago. You should encode / escape / transform data _when changing the context_. But this is not a real problem. As long as escaping happened somewhere, I'm fine with it :)

Comment: @rodneyrehm Foreach also would not work in this case. I am calling the saved meta keywords. home, trash, world, ... so I just need to blow them apart

Comment: Excusemewhat? The code snipped you provided translates perfectly to a foreach-loop. If there are other issues around, you might want to post that code, too.

Comment: @rodneyrehm Its all saved together. so we cant use foreach? right? $page_keywords = $row["page_keywords"]; // home, trash, world, sorry I left this out of the question  $tagclouds = explode(",", $tagclouds);